# What to do when something mess up my screen resolution?

Tags: nvidia, wine, display-resolution

Thief: The Dark Project on Wine crashed so I had to kill it with x-kill.
After doing so this is how my screen looked like:
[image]

(The left and the right side of the screen was black and non interactive but it is not visible on the screenshot)

The only thing that helped me was killing the desktop with xkill than reloging in, but is there any better way to get back the normal screen resolution?

Comment: And clicking with the mouse in this broken resolution mode clicks else than where the pointer is.

Answer (score 1):

```
xrandr --auto
```

resets your resolution to the standard. This will set the resolution for the first monitor, so if you use an external one or have any other setup you'll additionally need to specify the output using the `--output` option.

Comment: Thanks, I can click now and the size of the black nothing decreased, but it is still there. :-(

Comment: I didn't see the black nothing until just now, honestly I have no idea what that is. Did `xrandr --auto` reset your resolution to normal though?